# Change scheme for postgres extension on heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

We have an existing heroku App that we sometimes `pg:backups restore` to other apps.
Restoring fails since August 1st (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2446)

The existing app has extenions in `public`, newly created apps have extensions in `heroku_ext`. So I wanted to move the extensions to `heroku_ext`

```
some-app::DATABASE=> alter extension hstore set schema heroku_ext;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema heroku_ext
```

Schemas:

```
some-app::DATABASE=> \dn
       List of schemas
    Name    |     Owner
------------+----------------
 heroku_ext | postgres
 public     | some-user
```

Extensions (just showing one, for brevity)

```
some-app::DATABASE=> \dx
                                            List of installed extensions
        Name        | Version |   Schema   |                              Description
--------------------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
 hstore             | 1.7     | public     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
```

I can not drop/recreate the extension since there are hstore columns depending on it. How can I change the schema of the extension?

UPDATE:

got in touch with heroku and they say they are working on the issue and provided following info as workarounds:

> Manually migrating Postgres plugins by:
>
> pulling the affected database into a local database manually migrating
> the relevant extensions locally creating a new database on the app
> pushing the local DB with migrated extensions into the new database
> promoting the new database Manually updating schema references. For
> example:
>
> Changing all instances of WITH SCHEMA public; to WITH SCHEMA
> heroku_ext; and all instances of: DEFAULT public to DEFAULT heroku_ext
> by using find & replace in a text editor or by changing the output of
> pg_dump using sed

Comment: `permission denied for schema heroku_ext` - you need to be able to create objects in that schema if you are going to try this. You will also need to be the owner of the extension, and (I think) only some extensions support their schema being changed after installation.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHuxton

hstore is relocatable, i can move it to a new schema on a local PG installation.
This is more a heroku issue, i'd say because they introduced this limitation that extensions must be installed into "heroku_ext" schema in NEW apps. So we can not copy the DB.

Comment: The answer of Heroku is disappointing ☹️, as this introduces extra downtime when local operation and hence up and download is required. Also quite error prone. Hope they'll get this fixed.

Comment: Yeah, disappointing. They did not think this through for all the use cases.
Especially since some extensions are not relocatable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `extensions` flag when running `pg:backups:restore`.

```bash
heroku pg:backups:restore <backup id> STAGING_DATABASE_URL --extensions 'public.hstore,some_other_extension' -a example_app
```

Just released:

https://help.heroku.com/ZOFBHJCJ/heroku-postgres-extension-changes-faq

https://github.com/heroku/cli/pull/2043

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that solves my issue with `heroku pg:copy`

```bash
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --fork source-app-name::DATABASE --app target-app-name
```

Instead of copying database contents, this creates a clone of your original database, so the schema is compatible.

Hint: use

```bash
heroku pg:promote DB_NAME_OF_CLONE --app target-app-name
```

to replace the old (schema-incompatible DB) with the new one.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use `heroku pg:copy` between the source DB and the cloned DB. Trying so might result in a partly deleted schema.

Answer (score 0):

We're also seeing this.  It's a shame that Heroku has not publicly addressed this issue.  Note that even Heroku-created backups won't restore properly at this point without modification.

We have four applications that we are backing up.  Three appear to restore just fine, one fails.  The one that fails is using the gis extension--it appears that extensions that include data are failing.

Note that there is at least one extension out there that does not install to the public schema.  If you are going to do a mass search & replace on your backup file, make certain that you are only changing those going into the public schema.